# Transfer files from S3 to FTP

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, ftp, file-transfer

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to write a ruby code that can copy file (200mb) from s3 bucket to ftp without having to pass data from s3 to server and than to ftp, is there a way to make the stream go directly to the ftp server?

Answer (score 0):

You could use net-ssh to access the FTP server and then have it download from S3.  Hope that helps!

Comment: If I have ftp user and pass it's enough ?